# Why do Mugato's guys kill this person?

Tags: plot-explanation, zoolander-2

In Zoolander 2 (2016), I really don't understand Why Mugato's guys kill Justin Bieber.

In the final scenes Derek Zoolander asks Mugato about Justin Bieber's murder. 
But he didn't answer.

Comment: Seeing how this seems to happen right at the start of the movie, I have a hard time recognizing this as an actual spoiler.

Comment: I think Mugato did answer . he said : really? That was a perfect answer. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ben Stiller explained to Jimmy Fallon on *The Tonight Show*](http://time.com/4213558/ben-stiller-justin-bieber-zoolander/):

> Ben Stiller won’t give away too many spoilers for *Zoolander 2*, but
>   he has confirmed that Justin Bieber, playing himself, dies in one of
>   the early scenes. He explained to Jimmy Fallon on The Tonight Show
>   that **he always wanted to kill of Biebs — and even wrote the scene in the
>   original 2010 script.**
>
> But in the six years since that draft, Bieber has become a rather
>   divisive figure. So the “What Do You Mean” singer’s death in an early
>   scene of the film has been greeted alternately with despair or
>   pleasure, depending on audience members (and no doubt their ages).
>
> “We wrote the first script for it in 2010, and he was in it, but he
>   was young, new Justin Bieber. But **now he’s this cultural lightening
>   rod so his death in the movie, people just fill it—it’s sort of like a
>   Rorschach Test for people.**”